# Unresolved reference: Parcelize after adding necessary tools in gradle and updating to kotlin latest version

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, annotations, parcel

I am trying to annotate a data class with @parcelize and get the following error -

[image]

Here is my gradle file -

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {

    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'verte_internal_keystore'
            keyPassword ANDROID_STORE_PASSWORD
            storeFile file('verte_internal_keystore.jks')
            storePassword ANDROID_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.twoverte"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 16
        versionName ".3.4.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        buildConfigField "java.util.Date", "BUILD_TIME", "new java.util.Date(" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "L)"
    }

    File signFile = project.file('keyInfos.properties')
    if (signFile.exists()) {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        properties.load(new FileInputStream(signFile))
        signingConfigs {
            release {
                storeFile file(project.file(properties['keystore.filename']))
                storePassword properties['keystore.password']
                keyAlias properties['keystore.alias']
                keyPassword properties['keystore.password']
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {

    ....

    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    productFlavors {

    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.0.0'
    configurations {
        all {
            exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
            exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
        }
    }

    //Room components
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.3'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.3'

    //Lifecycle components
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.1.0'

    fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.cocosw:bottomsheet:1.0@aar'
    implementation 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.1.4'
    implementation 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.4'
    implementation 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-im:4.1.4'
    implementation 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-extensions:4.1.4'
    implementation 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-sasl-provided:4.1.4'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.6.30'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.6.0'
    implementation 'io.michaelrocks:libphonenumber-android:8.9.14'

    // Preferred for scheduling background jobs when new push notifications are received.
    // It provides a JobScheduler-compatible API that works on all recent versions of
    // Android (API level 14+) that have Google Play services installed.
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'

    implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'de.greenrobot:greendao:2.1.0'
    implementation 'io.github.rockerhieu:emojicon:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0'
    implementation 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.4.2'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.3'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:1.2.4'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
    implementation 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.4.2'
    implementation 'net.opacapp:multiline-collapsingtoolbar:27.1.1'
    implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.23295'
    implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
    implementation 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:3.0.0'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.3'


    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.7.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:2.1.4'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:picasso-transformations:2.2.1'
    implementation 'com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:2.0.0'


    implementation(name: 'appbase', ext: 'aar')
    implementation(name: 'greendao', ext: 'aar')
    implementation(name: 'chat', ext: 'aar')
    implementation(name: 'ffmpeg', ext: 'aar')
    implementation(name: 'imagecropper', ext: 'aar')
    implementation(name: 'imagepicker', ext: 'aar')
    implementation(name: 'webrtc', ext: 'aar')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

What am I missing? I can't seem to get the compiler to know @Parcelize annotation

I have tried to update the kotlin version, checked multiple previous questions about this issue and did not find anything relevant to assist me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated Answer:**

`kotlin-android-extensions` plugin is *deprecated*.

Now you have to add dependency in `app` level `build.gradle` file like below:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions-runtime:1.7.10
```

**Old Answer:**

Change your `build.gradle` to add `kotlin-android-extensions` in below order.

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Beside this you have enable [experimental feature](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html#enabling-experimental-features) to use it

```
androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}
```

Comment: `kotlin-android-extensions`  plugin is deprecated you should implement  `implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions-runtime:1.7.10"` insted.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have any dependency to the package `kotlinx.android.parcel`.

Add this to your dependency in `build.gradle`

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions-runtime:1.3.61"
```

Answer (score 0):

## Simply use kotlin-parcelize plugin:

```
id 'kotlin-parcelize' //  Or apply plugin: 'kotlin-parcelize'
```

And then, use the newest import

```
import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize
```